# What's the meaning of the French verb "rider"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, france, définition

I want to know what's the meaning of the French verb "rider" & the meaning of it in this sentence "je rid, ride, je fais du rodéo" in Eva & Kidaki song "rodéo"

Answer (score 8):

Despite this word ending with 'er', it is an anglicism used by snowboarders, skateboarders... and just means 'to practice their activity'.

It is most of the time pronounced with a strong French accent: /ʁajde/ (courtesy of @jlliagre).

Usage example: "Tu viens rider avec nous cette après-midi?"

Answer (score 4):

Hors le contexte de la question, il existe un verbe *rider* qui signifie *former des rides*, soit sur la peau à cause de la vieillesse, soit sur d'autres surfaces, par exemple à cause du vent sur l'eau.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I now that rider means plisser or to practice at skating but the meaning doesn't match at this sentence so that's why I asked...so please can anyone tell me the meaning of the sentence which is "je ride, ride, je fais du rodéo"

Comment: @Zuko Literally, "I ride, I ride, I do rodeo". I see this comes from the song "Rodéo" by Eva. If I interpret it correctly, the singer seems to bragging about how independent she is, how she has no faults, how many people watch her videos and just how great she is. You'd probably need a native speaker in touch with French youth culture to untangle all the colloquialisms.

Answer (score 4):

Here *ride* is the English verb "to ride" used as is in French.

*Je ride* means "I ride", possibly a motocycle or it is just a metaphor showing he is "easy riding" the road (of success), i.e. going ahead.

There are other similar metaphors like:

> *la concu j'la vois dans le rétro* (*concu* = *concurrence*)

I see the competition in the rear view mirror, i.e. I'm well ahead competition.

*Je fais du rodéo* is referring to *[rodéos urbains](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rod%C3%A9o_urbain)* "urban rodeos" by quad or motorcycle (wheeling, drifting and the likes). The Wikipedia definition translates to:

> Downtown riding of two-wheelers or quad bikes as a dangerous and noisy practice on unsuitable terrain.

Comment: Comme si la francais n'était pas assez difficile sans importer des anglicismes!

Comment: @OscarBravo Il y a toujours eu des emprunts d'une langue à l'autre... Mais en effet, vu l'état du monde, c'est presque exclusivement des emprunts à l'anglais (parfois même des remplacements purs et simples qui n'apportent rien)... Je pense (ou je crains) que ça arrive dans toutes les langues et que ça s'accélère. Cependant, les francophones rient sous cape chaque fois qu'ils réalisent le nombre de mots anglais issus du français (environ 1/3 du vocabulaire anglais).

Comment: @MathieuDubois Bah ouah! L'Angleterre était une colonie française depuis quelques siècles...

Comment: @OscarBravo *Colonie* n'est pas le terme adéquat, ou alors,il faut aussi dire que la France était une colonie allemande depuis quelques siècles...

Comment: @OscarBravo De toute façon, il suffit de remonter suffisamment loin pour trouver un ancètre commun à la plupart des mots anglais et français. Par exemple ***to ride*** est apparenté à **raid** déjà adopté en français au dix-neuvième siècle, apparenté aussi à **rade** (de Brest) que l'on a emprunté à l'anglais au quinzième siècle. Rien de nouveau sous le soleil.

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord avec vos 2 commentaires (votre exemple est amusant). Là où Oscar Bravo n'a pas totalement tort, c'est que le rythme des emprunts me semble accélérer.